# database connectivity using jsp

Tags: jsp, ms-access

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Inline Editing: Form Controls</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline-editing.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Presidents.css">
</head>
<body>
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Presidents");

        String sql = "SELECT PresidentID, FirstName, LastName, Bio FROM Presidents";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        out.write("<h1>Presidents</h1>");
        out.write("<p>Double click on any cell to edit the field. Click off the field to save your change.</p>");
        out.write("<table>");
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            out.write("<tr id='" + rs.getString("PresidentID") + "'>");
/*line 31*/         out.write("<td class="editable" title='FirstName'>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + "</td>");
/*line 32*/         out.write("<td class="editable" title='LastName'>" + rs.getString("LastName") + "</td>");
/*line 33*/     out.write("<td class="editable" title='Bio'>" + rs.getString("Bio") + "</td>");
            out.write("</tr>");
        }
        out.write("</table>");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.write("failed: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (rs != null) rs.close();
        if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        if (conn != null) conn.close();
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following errors for lines 31 ,32 ,33

```
The method write(String, int, int) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
Syntax error on token "editable", , expected
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: First of all don't write database connection logic in jsp ever.

Comment: Harry Joy is correct, you should be using servlets or some other backend logic to handle database queries. JSP is normally just the dumb module which displays the data coming from the backend. Have a look at some MVC tutorials when you have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (rs.next()) 
        {
            out.write("<tr id='" + rs.getString("PresidentID") + "'>");
/*line 31*/         out.write("<td class=\"editable\" title='FirstName'>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + "</td>");
/*line 32*/         out.write("<td class=\"editable\" title='LastName'>" + rs.getString("LastName") + "</td>");
/*line 33*/     out.write("<td class=\"editable\" title='Bio'>" + rs.getString("Bio") + "</td>");
            out.write("</tr>");
        }
```

You are not escaping " in class name of tag. Also consider my comment **never write business logic in jsp**. Do database connectivity in servlet. Jsp should be only used for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotation marks (or use single quotes).

Change this:

```
out.write("<td class="editable" title='FirstName'>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + "</td>");
```

to this:

```
out.write("<td class=\"editable\" title='FirstName'>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + "</td>");
```

or this:

```
out.write("<td class='editable' title='FirstName'>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + "</td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo:

```
out.write("<td class="editable" ...
```

should be

```
out.write("<td class='editable' ...
```

instead.